# Implementação em objective-C de classe Carro

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tenho esse código e gostaria de saber se essa forma de implementar é válida em objective-C.

```
@interface Carro : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSUInteger ano;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *modelo;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger ano;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger qtdGasolina;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger marchaAtual;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Você definiu a propriedade ano duas vezes. A forma correta é usando o modificador *assign*. 
Utiliza-se *copy* em objetos que tem uma contraparte mutável, como NSString - NSMutableString e NSArray - NSMutableArray.

Por exemplo, dado o seguinte código:

```
NSMutableString *modelo = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Fusca"];
Carro *carro = [Carro new];
carro.modelo = modelo;
[modelo setString:@"Kombi"];
```

Se o atributo *modelo* fosse definido como *assign*, ao modificar a String para Kombi, o valor do atribudo do objeto Carro também mudaria, o que em geral não é o esperado.